My Flutter IOS App Have Connection Problem
My Flutter IOS App Have Connection Problem
Hello I have created new flutter app and it works fine in android but on IOS internet working fine in simulator but in release inter net not working
I need internet work in IOS release

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Add this key to you ios/Runner/info.plist:
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

As mentioned in Apple Documentation:

A Boolean value indicating whether App Transport Security restrictions are disabled for all network connections.

More detail about NSAppTransportSecurity Apple Documentation
